# Frequency of getter access

Tags: c#, .net, properties

As getters in C# may be relatively costly, I wonder if they will be called every time or if the compiler will do any optimizations.

Let's have a look on this:

```
List<A> CurrentList{ get; }

void DoSomethingWithList()
{
    if(CurrentList.Count > 42)
    {        
        foreach(A processingA in CurrentList)
        {
            A.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Will the "CurrentList" getter really be called twice?

Comment: If the compiler were to cache the result and only call it once, then it wouldn't be the "current list", now would it? It would simply be "the list", and it would always and forever be the same list.

Comment: Getter is relatively costly?

Comment: @JörgWMittag If the compiler or runtime could tell it hasn't and won't be be updated between calls the compiler could be sure the last `CurrentList` was the current list and save the extra function call. Also the compiler might figure out that since `processingA` is never used in the loop, the first call in the `if` is the only one it cares about.  @BooleanAssange perhaps you mean `processingA.DoSomething();`

Comment: I assume the JITTER would optimize gets anyway.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know too much about property getter optimisations, but Pete's answer seems to cover the topic adequately.  Essentially, because a getter is nothing but syntactic sugar for a Getter Method, then very few guarantees can be made about its execution and, subsequently, optimisations like Memoization can't always be used.

### But more importantly

If your properties are costly, then you're doing it wrong.  Using a `getter` should be cheap and should not modify your object's state.  If you find that you have a `getter` that violates either of those points then it really should be a **method** instead.

Comment: in the world of ViewModel, properties can be costly ***BUT*** the code inside should be async, and when the processing is done, there will be a notification notifying about the changes. Sometimes method cannot replace properties, especially when working with ViewModel and binding (such as in WPF).

Answer (score 5):

It will get called twice in general - simply implement the getter to increment a counter each time it is called and run the code. The compiler doesn't know the difference between your property and one which will change state on every call, any more than if it were calling a method on the object. If the property is automatic or is a simple field access (and possibly for other simple cases), then the compiler may inline it, and so it could end up being optimized to a single access if no barriers exist between the uses.

Do your own optimisations to cache the result (either in the client code or in the getter), or do not use properties for costly computations.

Comment: The general rule with properties is "do not use properties for costly computations."

Comment: It's worth noting that when talking about optimization, "write some code that touches the thing that would otherwise be untouched" will invalidate your results!

Answer (score 0):

If you just traced in Debug you would see it called
Get is not that expensive
But you could reference a backing field directly

```
    List<int> currentList = new List<int>() { 1 };
    List<int> CurrentList { get { return currentList; } }
    void DoSomethingWithList()
    {
        if (currentList.Count > 42)
        {
            foreach (int processingA in currentList)
            {
                //A.DoSomething();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The getter call won't get cached but it *might* get [inlined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion).  Since the code inside the getter call is simply a field read, inlining the code would have a similar effect on performance as a cache, and would have the advantage that any side effects would be faithfully reproduced.

If the getter performed more logic than simply returning a field, it would be less likely to get inlined.

You can't force a getter to be inlined, but you can encourage it, like this:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
List<int> CurrentList { get { return currentList; } }
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162541/is-the-c-sharp-compiler-smart-enough-to-optimize-this-code) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303924/how-to-force-inline-functions-in-c).

Answer (score -1):

Getter in C# is just a special method returning some value, no more or less. So if you need to call the method twice, it will surely be used twice.

In your specific example, the first call to obtain the Count, the second call to loop through all the elements of the returned value (which is a List).

If there is some backing field for your property, then the first call obtaining `Count` would do nothing expensive or considerable, the `Count` is always there to be quickly accessed.

However if your property always create a new `List<A>` on every access, something like this:

```
List<A> CurrentList {
    get {
       return new List<A>(....);
    }
}
```

Then it might be something wrong with your code here. In this case, you need to obtain the list first before doing anything on the returned result (getting `Count` and loop through all elements), like this:

```
void DoSomethingWithList() {
  var list = CurrentList;
  if(list.Count > 42)
  {        
    foreach(A processingA in list)
    {
        processingA.DoSomething();
    }
  }
}
```

Again I would like to emphasize that if you use some backing field for your property, your code should be fine (and cannot be different to be better). 
Everything you put in the `get` closure will finally result in a getter method like this:

```
List<A> getMethod(){
    return new List<A>(....);
}
```

Nothing special here, property is just a wrapper of getter and setter method. Instead of using 2 separate methods, we can just use 1 property and use the `=` intuitively. In another point of view, Property  looks like a wrapper around some backing field (in almost cases, because some properties don't have backing field), so it adds another logic layer to the access point of the backing field (such as checking the difference between new value and the current value of the backing field to raise some PropertyChanged event, ...).

Comment: Why is the world would you create a new list on every call? var list = CurrentList; is not going to be more efficient than just referencing CurrentList twice.

Comment: @Paparazzi please read the answer carefully, ***in case `CurrentList` always creates a new `List`***, you access it twice meaning you create the `List` twice, which is not efficient. Using `foreach` directly on `CurrentList` ***won't*** reference the `CurrentList` because there is not any to reference here, a new `List` is still created behind the scene (you won't see this of course), it's still stored in memory in the local scope of the method. The second time accessing `CurrentList`, there will be another `List` created and stored in the local memory. So you have 2 local `List`.

Comment: I can read.  Why in the world would you crate a new List with every call.   No one can really save anything to the List.   Good name.

Comment: @Paparazzi It's just a supposition, and in reality you can have such property. Each time a property need to ***evaluate*** a dynamic data which can change over time, it's not static, so it's practical.

Comment: Practically useless.   The next call does NOT get dynamic data if it is a static new.

Comment: @Paparazzi not sure what you mean, please be more ***clever*** - The ***new List<...>()*** is just the ***last line of code block***, you populate the list upper there. My code is just some kind of simple explanation. You don't even know that?

Comment: @Paparazzi `(....)` is the place holder of dynamic data, you can put any query returning `IEnumerable<A>` there, understand?

Comment: Yes the programmer can put anything they want there.  The program however cannot.

Comment: @Paparazzi again it's mainly for illustrative purpose, but still you can put dynamic query there, you mean we cannot? Think about this query `someItemModels.Where(e => e.IsChecked)` - yes `IsChecked` of each item here can be changed by ***user interaction*** which is dynamic, at least at the time you access to `CurrentList`.

Comment: Buy a vowel.  What about CurrentList .Add("new item")?  Next call does not get "new item".

Comment: @Paparazzi when you declare a property like that, you must be careful when using it. It's not persitent, so why adding item to it? It's just a snapshot of data, get it, process the data ... (not cumulate the data). ***And again I just suppose what the OP should do in that case***. We do not declare such property frequently, it's rarely used, but it surely can be helpful in some scenario.

Comment: No kidding must be careful using your properties.   Nothing about that implementationindicates it is read only nor does the question ask for read only.

Comment: @Paparazzi You need to understand the purpose of your property, use it in just a normal way, when it is considered as a snapshot, there is not any logic to add item to it. You always consider properties as persistent, there should be always backing fields? so you just do not understand the actual nature of property.

Comment: Nothing about the question indicates snapshot.  Nothing would stop me from CurrentList.Add("new item").   That is not how you implement read only.   Done with you.

Comment: @Paparazzi and nothing would stop you from `CurrentList.Clear`? when it should not? Nothing would stop you from using Reflection to access non public members, you can do many ***dangerous*** things if you want, but when you feel it's illogic or not suitable at all, you won't do. Also I have to accept the truth that we should use some readonly `List<>` in this case (so that it does not expose any method to add/remove item), however creating such kind of `List` requires more CPU processing. Also compared to what you do in other languages,such as Javascript,you'll see this freedom is just trivial

Comment: @Paparazzi the OP said this ***getters in C# may be relatively costly*** - so if the property has some backing field, I don't think that's the case, there won't be anything ***relatively costly*** here, so I think the kind of property getting dynamic data may be the case of the OP. At first you fight against me about the ***static new List*** because you did not understand how dynamic the place holder `(.....)` could be, now you fight against me about readonly property, yes it's readonly because it has just a getter, but in fact it is not readonly by what you meant.

Comment: Hopeless is hopless

Comment: @Paparazzi you can be hopeless in many things, so please don't be impolite before I call you an idiot.

Comment: Hopeless less hope

Comment: @Paparazzi idiots will never understand a simple thing, e.g: when you say *I'm hopeless*, it does not mean exactly what you are hopeless with, so what if you're hopeless with walking slower or speaking slower? In this case you're actually hopeless with understanding what hopeless (stand alone) can mean. I'm hopeless with spending less than $100 a day, understand?

Comment: Too deep for me.  I do know when I lose change to a property that is not good.  Lehopess